# Is there a way to check a JBoss server is available after restarting with Bamboo, before continuing with Selenium

Tags: maven, selenium, jboss, bamboo

We are running Selenium tests as the last step in a Bamboo deployment plan, to a JBoss  server.

After deploying the new EAR & WAR files, the JBoss server is restarted, using maven via `wildfly:execute-commands`.

The very next step is to start the Selenium tests.

Selenium is getting a HTTP 404, presumably because the JBoss server isn't actually ready to talk to the world just yet.
If we re-deploy, after removing the JBoss restart, the Selenium tests perform without incident.

Is there a way to check, and wait, either from Bamboo, Maven, Selenium, or some 3rd party tool, until the JBoss server is ready to serve pages.

- Bamboo 5.4.2
- JBoss 8.1.0.Final
- Maven 3.2.1
- Selenium 2.43.1

Answer (score 1):

WildFly state (this is the actual name of JBoss 8) can be checked with its CLI tool or through its HTTP/JSON API. Have a look to this blog post : http://antoniogoncalves.org/2014/07/20/your-tests-assume-that-jboss-is-up-and-running/. It's dealing with a similar issue.